# How to modify real servicing environment when using glassfish?

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

I have a dilemma.

I’m developing a web app using glassfish4.0 opensource edition, springframework MVC.
How do I apply modified classes without stopping application, after launching this application?

I know `dynamic reload` in `glassfish`. But this function is needed a few times. If application has a payment service, then this is very critical issue. So I wonder: how do I apply modified classes without stopping application?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution would be using 2 Server (for example called: "green" and "blue") (this is also recommend for other reasons) with a load balancer in front.

If you need to modify the application, then configure the load balancer to send every request to "green". Then wait some time to make sure that every request that was earlyer sended to "blue" is done. Now you can update "blue" (shutdown,...). After "blue" is up, you reconfigure the loadbalancer. Now do the same thing with "green"...

This is sometimes called "green blue deployment".